# Concrete5: Why does my block fail to save the first time?

Tags: concrete5

I am using 5.6.3.4 and using Designer Content to create blocks. I have customised the blocks by adding tabs. Other than that, it's pretty straightforward and everything is functioning well.

My problem is when I try to add and save a new block the first time, it keeps showing me the 'loading' icon but does not save the block. If I refresh the page and try adding the block again, it works. Sometimes it happens randomly and when I refresh the page and save, it works. Is there anything that's causing this and how can I fix this?

I have all cache turned off and am trying this on my localhost. The site does not have any other add-ons installed other than Designer Content. The site is using Bootstrap.

Comment: I assume that there's an AJAX error. Can you please open the chrome developer console and check the response of all AJAX requests? F12, Network, XHR and then click on each request and then its response.

Comment: @Remo For some reason I didn't experience this on Chrome. I was originally trying this on Firefox. I also experienced this while working on my localhost. Probably my local server was slow or it could be an issue with Firefox. I was working on a project for a client. I sent the project and the client never complained about this issue. So it must be my local server or browser.

I'd like to know if anyone else has experienced this.

Comment: I've built more than just a few websites, but never had that problem nor heard of it. If there's a bug in the save procedure this could happen, but that wouldn't be a random thing.

Answer (score -1):

Had same issue, which was caused by tracking pixel code(javascript error).
Changed script to display code only when page is not in edit mode